# Using Nginx as for api gateway

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a react node mongodb website that has one route and basically one post request for collecting forms.

I have been at this step for a few hours. I have gotten the build folder to be read, but every article on google gives me a similiar set of instructions for location /api/ and none of them seem to work

here is my nginx config right now

```
server 
{
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
server_name {{amazon public ip}};

location / {
root /var/www/html/build;
index index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri /index.html;
}

location /api/ {
  proxy_pass http://{{amazon private ip}}:5000/;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

}
```

then i pm2 my server.js on port 5000 and it should work right... right? ;-;

Comment: Instead of saying something does not work, describe clearly how it failed (exact error message, things from browser developer tools or elsewhere). That makes a question answerable.

Comment: im not sure there is an error message. It just doesnt post. but systemctl status nginx.service is all green and  the routes work in development. if you have a suggestion as to where i can look to give you some idea of whats wrong id love to.

Comment: When a React app made calls to backend APIs and failed, you can see detailed error messages in console/network tabs of the browser's developer tools. If you didn't check those yet, start from there.

Comment: 404 to /api/leads on a route that works in development.

Comment: you said the secret word and that is production